# git ignore not ignoring a file when using GCloud's gcloudignore

Tags: python, gcloud, gitignore, gcloudignore

I have a rule to ignore secret.py (production.py in my case) and once I added .gcloudignore, github stopped following that rule...
Is there some sort of a rule overriding between gitignore and gcloudignore that I am not aware of?

```
my-project/
    .git
    .gitignore
    my-project/
        .gcloudignore
        settings/
            base.py
            local.py
            production.py
```

my .gitignore:

```
my-project/my-project/settings/production.py
my-project/my-project/settings/local.py
```

my .gcloudignore:

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore

*.sqlite3
settings/local.py
```

End result is that the 'local.py' is NOT pushed to google cloud NOR github.
However, 'production.py' IS pushed to github AND gcloud.

Comment: I wonder if you had accidentally submitted a change to git that included production.py? Once it's there, .gitignore will not apply to it. Do a `git log production.py` to see, and if it's there, do a `git rm --cached production.py` to remove it from repo.

Comment: That was it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MykWillis, can you write an answer to help others?

Comment: sure thing - glad it helped @willer2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had previously (perhaps accidentally) submitted a change to git that included `my-project/my-project/settings/production.py`, then it will remain a part of the repository even if it is subsequently added to `.gitignore`.

Assuming you are at the root of your project, you can use

```
$ git log my-project/my-project/settings/production.py
```

to see its git history. If it is present in your repo, you can do

```
$ git rm --cached my-project/my-project/settings/production.py
```

to [remove it from the repo](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached), but keep it in your local (working) environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are enforcing to ignore the rules applied before.

Though make sure that the cloudignore is enable via

```
gcloud config set gcloudignore/enabled true
```

And make sure to place .gcloudignore - > in the root of your project / basically where you .git .gitignore reside.

Comment: The issue is that gcloud's ignore file is working fine. It's the git ignore file that isn't following the ignore rule. I guess the question is 'why are gitignore and gcloudignore interfering with each other at all?' Shouldn't they be completely disjoint?